# Is there anyway of retrieving unsaved Photoshop work?

Tags: photoshop

I foolishly did not save some stock photos I was using for a project only copy+pasted them, and in the process of updating growl, and an apple update for Quicktime Photoshop stopped responding. It didn't say the application was not responding but every time I clicked on a window for Photoshop it just made the unhappy you can't do this sound.

Comment: If they're stock photos, it stands to reason that someone has copies of them.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The “XML Round Trip” method and more...

1. Open the project in MS Project.
2. File, Save As, Save As File.
3. When prompted select to save with “All Enterprise Custom Fields”.
4. In the file dialog select the Save as type: XML
5. Save the file to your local computer.
6. Once saved, close the project (don’t forget to check in!) and 
   reopen the saved XML file, when prompted choose to import ‘As a new 
   project’.
7. Once opened, select Save As and save the project to the project 
   server using the exact same project name.
8. When prompted say yes to overwrite the existing project (you did 
   check it in right?)
9. Publish and your done.
10. read more information:
    http://www.techrepublic.com/forums/questions/how-to-restore-photoshop-project/
    if previous actions didn`t give the result.